# EasyPHP Devserver v17.0 Windows 10 Install

Tags: easyphp, devserver

I installed EasyPHP Devserver v17.0 on new laptop and I get a message that code execution cannot proceed because MSVCR110.dll was not found when attempting to start.  I reinstalled and get the same error.  I found the dll on my system.

Directory of C:\Windows\System32

11/05/2012  10:26 PM           849,360 msvcr110.dll
               1 File(s)        849,360 bytes

What do I do to resolve this startup issue?

PS
I have it running successfully on a different Windows 10 laptop just fine and did not do anything different when I did the install??

Answer (score 0):

I dug deeper and found a previous answer under Easyphp : msvcr110.dll is missing.

I downloaded and installed the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 is also required. Here's the download link for that one: microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Sorry for the "unnecessary question.